# Real Analysis book with pictures and ideas of proofs

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am taking real analysis course in my graduate class of Maths. My classes will start in 3 months. I have studied real analysis but not  very rigorously. Whenever I see theorem I have no idea on how to prove it or even how do I start it. I understand when I read them. But I cannot reproduce them in my own way when needed.

Basically I want to redo it again before my actual classes.

Can anyone suggest me book which contains pictorial and diagrams for proofs and also **idea of proof is given** with each proof. I feel like as I lack tools for proofs. This will help me a lot

Thanks

Comment: Someone suggested to me that, when reading a real analysis book without illustrations, I should always have pencil and paper handy so I could draw pictures for it myself.

Comment: Look at Victor Bryant's [**Yet Another Introduction to Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/052138835X). I've written about this book several times since 2000 -- google its title along with my name.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks i have seen the book ..It is a good book .Can you suggest slightly advanced text

Comment: A little more advanced, with lots of intuition (and I think pictures) is Bressoud's [**A Radical Approach to Real Analysis**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0883857472). Bressoud's book is less advanced than Pugh's book mentioned below (a book I like a lot, by the way) and a little more advanced than Abbott's book mentioned below (another book I like a lot).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual book of real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619663/visual-book-of-real-analysis)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Understanding Analysis by Abbott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441928669) . It's a pretty rigorous book but it was written with the beginner in mind. It may help you review.

Comment: Abbott's book lacks many pictures though.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found [this GEM](http://www.amazon.in/Basic-Course-Real-Analysis-ebook/dp/B00HSSC4C4/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1430235504&sr=1-1&keywords=elementary+real+analysis) that has proof strategies, motivation for every proof with over 100 pictures:

---

#### Edit by non-OP:

The link overhead is broken. I divine [this](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-basic-course-in-real-analysis) to have been intended:

Ajit Kumar and S. Kumaresan. *A Basic Course in Real Analysis* (2014).

Answer (score 2):

C.C.Pugh 's  Real Mathematical Analysis is a very good book in this regard.It contains all the proofs with pictures.

Comment: can't find it online ?

Comment: Why? Google shows it

Comment: Can you provide link