# What books pictorialize real analysis, similarly to Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation

I am physics major doing my undergrad (currently in year 2) and was wondering. Are there books for real analysis similar to Tristan Needham's [Visual Complex Analysis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/149800.Visual_Complex_Analysis?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=q4IdJmrIBW&rank=1)?

Comment: That book is my favorite .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real Analysis book with pictures and ideas of proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253247/real-analysis-book-with-pictures-and-ideas-of-proofs)

Comment: Duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619663.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the text "[Understanding Analysis](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/845794.Understanding_Analysis)"
by Stephen Abbott.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer real analysis by S. Kumaresan. This book has a nice geometric intuition to many rigorous concepts.